# failed to build wheel for psycopg2?

Tags: django, heroku, web-deployment

Hi after i re write my source code
and cloning my website from heroku

i get this error

LOGS :

```
       psycopg/psycopgmodule.c: In function ‘psyco_is_main_interp’:

       psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:689:18: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘PyInterpreterState’ {aka ‘struct _is’}

         689 |     while (interp->next)

             |                  ^~

       error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1

       ----------------------------------------

   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-t_xxbtyy/psycopg2-binary/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-t_xxbtyy/psycopg2-binary/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-cevcg2_6/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.9/psycopg2-binary Check the logs for full command output.
```

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.

!     Push failed

Any fixes ??
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check [this post](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/858)

It suggests updating psycopg2 and python